# Apache-Superset Single Date selector in dashboards filter or custom date filter

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to use a single date selection with <= (less than or equal to) functionality in the Apache superset.

Is there any way to add a custom date filter in the superset where the user can select only a single date, not the date range?